# Position a title and message in the centre, whilst postioning a sub message at the start

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to position a title in the centre and a message which will start from the same x axis point as the title, whilst positioning a sub message from the start on the left:

[image]

I've tried the following CSS, but the two messages just stay close together, and the second message does not align with the title

```css
.container{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}

.divForSubMessageAndMessage{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: flex-start;
}

.message{
    justify-self: center;
    align-self: center;
}
```

```html
<div className="container">
    <h1>Title</h1>
    <div className="divForSubMessageAndMessage">
        <p className="subMessage">subMessage</p>
        <p className="message">Message</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Could you please add the HTML markup for your question? You might use absolute positioning &/or the transform property to nudge the inner box above its parent.

Comment: We need a [mcve] please

Comment: @j08691 its been added

Comment: You could remove .divForSubMessageAndMessage and use css grid for it. Or use positiong:relative on the .divForSubMessageAndMessage and position: absolute left: -100% on .subMessage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This cannot be done only with css, if `.title` width is not hard set. In addition, when using javascript, it is important to take into account the nuances - such as, for example, the width of `.title`. Here is an example for you as a starting point:

```js
position();
window.onresize = position;

function position() {
  const title = document.querySelector('.title');
  const titleWidth = document.querySelector('.title').offsetWidth;
  const subMessage = document.querySelector('.sub-message');
  const content = document.querySelector('.content');
  const gap = 16; // grid-gap
  subMessage.style.removeProperty('margin-right');
  content.style.removeProperty('margin-left');
  if (titleWidth < subMessage.offsetWidth) {
    subMessage.style.marginRight = titleWidth / 2 + gap / 2 + 'px';
    content.style.marginLeft = titleWidth / -2 - gap / 2 + 'px';
  }
}
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin:  0;
}

body:before {
  content: '';
  width: 1px;
  height: 100vh;
  inset: 0 auto 0 50%;
  position: fixed;
  background-color: green;
}

.grid {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto 1fr 1fr auto;
  grid-gap: 16px;
  padding: 16px;
}


.title {
  place-self: center;
  grid-column: span 4;
  align-self: center;
  text-align: center;
}

.sub-message {
  grid-column: span 2;
}

.content {
  grid-column: span 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid">
  <div class="title">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</div>
  <div class="sub-message">Sub message</div>
  <div class="content">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Sit, molestias, consectetur, laudantium perspiciatis accusantium aut officiis quo sed minima vero iusto quod illum repellendus delectus facilis quidem eius. Porro, assumenda recusandae omnis iste maiores sapiente modi praesentium aut repellendus ipsa nesciunt incidunt architecto? Placeat adipisci veritatis iusto quaerat possimus ullam!</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

A grid is much better suited than a flexbox for managing the overall layout of this particular design.

```css
body {
  font-family: sans-serif;
  margin: 2em 0;
  background: #f4f4f4;
}
.container {
  padding: 1em;
  background: silver;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
  gap: 1em 0;  
}
.title {
  grid-row: 1;
  grid-column: 2;
}
.message {
  grid-row: 2;
  grid-column: 2;
}
.subMessage {
  grid-row: 2;
  grid-column: 1;
}
.title, .message, .subMessage {
  background: #f4f4f4;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 0;
}
.title, .subMessage {
  width: 50%;
  height: 4rem;
}
.message {
  height: 12rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <h1 class="title">Title</h1>
  <p class="message">Message</p>
  <p class="subMessage">Sub message</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Ahh I made a mistake in the question, I've made edits this was one of my original thoughts